# How to enlarge image in ClipRRect while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using ClipRRect and Image Widget to show rounded Image.
But because the image is horizontally long, it has an unnatural roundness.

In the image below, red is ClipRRect and blue is image. The current program is the one above. But this is not what I want to do.

I want to enlarge the image greatly while maintaining the ratio like the second one and make it protrude from ClipRRect. The light blue part originally has an image, but it is not drawn because it protrudes from the ClipRRect.

[image]

Currently I'm writing this inside a Gridview and the size of the ClipRRect is not explicit.
Also image size is random.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  child: Image.network(str,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) =>
          Center(child: child),
   ....
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter constraints goes down.

GridView >> Image.Network >>  Center(this is taking full constraints)>> imageRender.

You can just return the child and it will take full space.

While you are using loading builder, it can be

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  child: Image.network(
    src,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) =>
        loadingProgress != null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : child,
  )
```

Comment: you missed some widgets: `ClipRRect` does not have `loadingBuilder` parameter

Comment: oh yes, edit mistake , thanks